# Is a patient who has an autoimmune disease immunocompromised?

Tags: immune-system, covid-19, influenza, autoimmune-disease, immunosuppressant

If a patient has an autoimmune disease - Hashimoto's Thyroiditis, for example - and is *not* on immunosuppressants, are they at a higher, lower or equal risk of ending up with COVID-19 (or any other catching illness)?

This assumes that the patient is otherwise healthy and in any age bracket (if there are age-related statistics someone would like to share, assume the patient is in the 20-30 y/o bracket).

Answer (score 1):

This type of data can only come from studies.  The ones I've looked at so far do not indicate that single organ autoimmune disease is a risk factor.

The risk factors they looked at in the study below were: age, smoking, cardiorespiratory disease, hypertension, cerebrovascular disease, chronic renal disease, immunodeficiency, hepatitis B infection, diabetes (type not specified), and cancer.

Hypertension is an odd factor and may relate to the concurrent use of ACEI drugs which may make people more prone to infection.

https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2002032

Comment: Does this apply to other contagious illnesses as well?